# Cypress.visit() is not working when passed URL in qs(query string)

Tags: cypress

I am trying to open a URL with the below code and passed the `qs(Query String)` parameter. In my `qs(Query String)` parameter I have 2 elements as below -

> 1. Client ID ('0000-11111-33333-44444-55555')
> 2. Redirect URL ('http://localhost:8088/api/callback')

1. If I pass the Redirect URL in a non-encoded format the test is terminated.
2. And if I pass the Redirect URL in the encoded format before calling `visit` cypress again encodes it and due to that the duel encoded callback URL is called and due to it's failing.
   See in below example -

> ```
> describe('Connect', function () {
>     beforeEach(() => {
>         cy.visit({
>             method: 'GET',
>             url: 'https://someURL.com/oauth2/authorize',
>             qs: {
>                 client_id: encodeURIComponent('0000-11111-33333-44444-55555'),
>                 redirect_uri: encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:8088/api/callback'),
>             }
>         });
>     });
>
>     it('Check connection', function () {
>         cy.contains('Success').should('be.visible');
>     });
> });
> ```

This produces the URL to visit -

```
https://open-ic.epic.com/Argonaut/oauth2/authorize?client_id=0000-11111-33333-44444-55555&redirect_uri=http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8088%252Fapi%252Fcallback
```

This is incorrect and this should be like -

```
https://someURL.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=0000-11111-33333-44444-55555&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8088%2Fapi%2Fcallback
```

In the above URLs observe `redirect_uri` is encoded twice which I think the issue.

Is there something I am missing to add here??

Comment: Have you tried removing your query string elements one by one?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha Yes, I tried removing the qs, and as per the recently updated question the parameter `redirect_uri` is causing the issue

Comment: What happens when you assemble the encoded URL by hand, then do a `cy.visit()` on it?

Comment: @MetaWhirledPeas If I try to pass an already encoded URL the same behavior appears that cy.visit() again encode it once again.